# Split and parse only specific characters from string using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to split and parse characters from an column and submit the parsed data into different column .

First the unwanted data need to be removed from the string and after that it needs to be split and to be saved into different column by adding prefix 19 before the year.

Input:

```
Col1
U_a65839_Jan87Apr88
U_b98652_Feb88Apr88
V_C56478_mar89Apr89
Q_d15634_Apr90Apr91
S_e15336_may91Apr93
NaN
```

Output

```
Col2       Col3
Jan1987   Apr1988
Feb1987   Apr1988
mar1987   Apr1988
Apr1987   Apr1988
may1987   Apr1988
  NaN        NaN
```

Code Snippet, What I have been trying so far:

```
df = pd.read_excel(open(r'C:\Users\Desktop\data1.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet1')

df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].partition("_")[2]
```

Please Suggest how to Execute it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you got

```
col_1 = [
    'U_a65839_Jan87Apr88',
    'U_b98652_Feb88Apr88',
    'V_C56478_mar89Apr89',
    'Q_d15634_Apr90Apr91',
    'S_e15336_May91Apr93',
    np.nan
]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col1': col_1
})
```

you can

```
# remove unwanted data
df['Col1'] = df.Col1.str.replace(
    '.*_', '', regex=True
)
# split first part
df['Col2'] = df.Col1.str[:5]
# split second part
df['Col3'] = df.Col1.str[5:]
# add 19
df['Col2'] = df.Col2.replace({'(\d\d)': r'19\1'}, regex=True)
df['Col3'] = df.Col3.replace({'(\d\d)': r'19\1'}, regex=True)
```

that gives

```
         Col1     Col2     Col3
0  Jan87Apr88  Jan1987  Apr1988
1  Feb88Apr88  Feb1988  Apr1988
2  mar89Apr89  mar1989  Apr1989
3  Apr90Apr91  Apr1990  Apr1991
4  May91Apr93  May1991  Apr1993
5         NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Before executing first line ,  df['Col1'] = df.Col1.str.replace(
    '.*_', '', regex=True
), I only need to process the Rows which are not blank, Any Suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean? Drop `NaN`  rows? In this case you can simply `df.dropna(inplace=True)`

Comment: I have tried to use it before the first line of script as df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].dropna(inplace=True) , But it gives error in the next line.

Comment: No... simply `df.dropna(inplace=True)` or, if you want to drop only rows with `NaN`s in `Col1`, you can do `df.dropna(subset=[`Col1`], inplace=True)`. Here you can read the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html